# Por que alguém com mais de 10 mil pontos se canditaria a ser Moderador?

Tags: debate, moderação, privilégios

Estava dando uma olhada nos privilégios que você ganha conforme consegue mais pontos e fiquei com uma dúvida.

Por que alguém com mais de 10 mil pontos se canditaria para ser ***Moderador***?

Pois com **2.000** as edições são automáticas.

E com **10.000** o usuário tem acesso as ferramentas de moderação.

O que alguém com mais de **10.000 de reputação** ganharia sendo moderador?

Apenas mais responsabilidade?